# My controller don't receive the IDs of an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a JavaScript function that uses AJAX request to send data to my controller on asp.net MVC. Look:

```
function verCarrinho() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Produto/Carrinho",
    data: { "carrinho": carrinho },
    success: function (e) {
    }
});
}
```

Where carrinho is an array with two properties. One of these properties is an ID that I need to send to my controller to use EF to make a query on my data base.

My ActioNResult on controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Carrinho(List<Carrinho> carrinho)
    {
        var ids = carrinho.Select(s => s.idLivro).ToList();
        var resultado = db.Produtos.Where(w => ids.Contains(w.idProduto));
        return PartialView("_Carrinho", resultado);
    }
```

The problem is: my variable "resultado" stay null! The AJAX is not sending the IDs. If I put a breakpoint on resultado I can see that AJAX send the objects, but I can't see the IDs.

I have a class same type of my parameter:

```
public class Carrinho
{
    public int idLivro;
    public int qtdProduto;
}
```

I don't know if I could be clear, but I hope you can help.

Thank you.

Comment: Turn the object into a JSON and send the JSON as a string to the call and then inside the method convert the string back into an object

Comment: @jcuenod Of course, my bad, sorry! I will do this now! Thank you all. I can't vote your answers because I don't have reputation for that, but I accepted my own answer like solution, it just I can do. See you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code based on a friend's code and it works. It's look like this:

```
namespace WebAppImaginario.Models
{
public class ItemCarrinho
  {
    public int idLivro { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Quantidade do Produto")]
    public int qtdProduto { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Nome do Produto")]
    public string nomeProduto { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Descrição do Produto")]
    public string descProduto { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Preço do Produto")]
    public decimal precProduto { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Desconto da Promoção")]
    public decimal descontoPromocao { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Imagem")]
    public byte[] imagem { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Carrinho(string hidCarrinho)
    {
        List<ItemCarrinho> listaCarrinho = new List<ItemCarrinho>();

        if (hidCarrinho != null)
        {
            var itens = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ItemCarrinho>>(hidCarrinho);

            foreach (var item in itens)
            {
                var qtd = int.Parse(new string(item.qtdProduto.ToString().Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()));
                if (qtd > 0)
                {
                    var idLivroNumerico = int.Parse(new string(item.idLivro.ToString().Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()));
                    var resultado = db.Produtos.Where(m => m.idProduto == idLivroNumerico).FirstOrDefault();
                    ItemCarrinho prod = new ItemCarrinho();
                    prod.idLivro = idLivroNumerico;
                    prod.qtdProduto = qtd;
                    prod.nomeProduto = resultado.nomeProduto;
                    prod.descProduto = resultado.descProduto;
                    prod.precProduto = resultado.precProduto;
                    prod.descontoPromocao = resultado.descontoPromocao;
                    prod.imagem = resultado.imagem;
                    listaCarrinho.Add(prod);
                }
            }
        }

        return View(listaCarrinho);
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
function setValueEnviar() {
$("#hiddenInputContainer").empty();

for (var i = 0; i < carrinho.length; i++) {
    var newInput = document.createElement('input');
    newInput.type = "hidden";
    newInput.value = JSON.stringify(carrinho[i]);
    newInput.name = 'data';
    $("#hiddenInputContainer").append(newInput);
 }
}

$('#formCarrinho').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#hidCarrinho').val(JSON.stringify(carrinho));
  document.formCarrinho.submit();
})
```

Those IDs are a form on my page and hidden input. I don't know if it is clear, but it works to me.

Thank you for all support.

Answer (score 0):

you need to `data: JSON.stringify({ "carrinho": carrinho })` and also add `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` to ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Object Literal Syntax !== JSON.

You need to [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) your `data` object in your ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax like `data: { "carrinho": carrinho }` can work, `$.ajax` does accept a `PlainObject` as `data` (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Your problem is that your variable `carrinho` is not conforming to the requirements of a `PlainObject`.

> The PlainObject type is a JavaScript object containing zero or more key-value pairs

http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject

Depending on what `carrinho` is, you may have success with `stringify` as an alternative:

```
function verCarrinho() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Produto/Carrinho",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "carrinho": carrinho }),
    success: function (e) {
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi. Still wrong :/! Thanks for the answer and thanks to ozil and Alex too! My AJAX is this way, now:

function verCarrinho() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Produto/Carrinho",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "carrinho": carrinho }),
    success: function (e) {
         $("#listaProdutos").html(e);
    }
  });
}

#listaProdutos is an empty ul tag. When I debug the result var on controller, there null value :(

Comment: @Pasch what is the output of `console.log(carrinho)`?

Comment: Hi. I changed my code based on a friend's code and it works. I will post it on a answer here, ok? If you can comment again, I will apreciate.